# How to using CEFSharp JavascriptObjectRepository in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

I want get javascript response,

and follow cef document to do,

this is my step,

first create a html file

```
...
<button onclick='test()'>click</button>
...
<script>
function test(){ 
  alert('123');
  callbackObj.getMessage('123');
}
</script>
```

and then I register javascript response method

```
CefSharpSettings.LegacyJavascriptBindingEnabled = true;
this.MyBrowser.JavascriptObjectRepository.Register("callbackObj", new PagaJavaScriptResponse(), true);
```

and create class to do PagaJavaScriptResponse

```
 public class PagaJavaScriptResponse
 {
   public void getMessage(string s)
   {
        ....
   }       
 }
```

next step to check the register is bound

```
var isBound = this.MyBrowser.JavascriptObjectRepository.IsBound("callbackObj");
```

the result is true,

last step to url http://127.0.0.1/index.html

```
this.MyBrowser.Address = @"http://127.0.0.1:8887/test.html";
```

here I think when I click button it should be return 123 to my method in C#, but not,

hot it's correct?

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#13-how-do-you-handle-a-javascript-event-in-c for an example of using `CefSharp.PostMessage`, you don't need to bind a class if you just need to send simple messages from javascript to .net

Comment: See also https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2775#issuecomment-498454221

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try a solution

just when page loaded excute this javascript

```
this.MyBrowser.WebBrowser.ExecuteScriptAsyncWhenPageLoaded(@"(async function() {await CefSharp.BindObjectAsync('callbackObj', 'bound');})();");
```

it's will work